# Mimic 3G network traffic of selected telco operator

Tags: networking, 3g, telecommunication

Currently, I need to perform some network communication with a mobile gateway.

The mobile gateway is expecting 3G network traffic of selected telco operator.

I was wondering, is there any I can mimic such traffic from my laptop? Or, from my 3G smartphone which is not subscribed to selected telco operator?

The reason I ask so is selected telco is a foreign telco. Hence, it is not possible to use its sim card locally.

***Is there any way, or any services, for me to mimic 3G network traffic from selected telco operator?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.simtest.it/ seems a good way to perform such testing. They provide access to real modem with different sim cards. You may control those modem remotely, by sitting comfortably in your air-con office.

Disclaim : I do not have any affiliate relationship with the above mentioned company.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about the 3G air interface, the easiest way is to get a SIM for that telco that supports roaming, or to get access to a modem/phone + SIM that stays in the home network, and that you can control remotely.

If people could easily simulate a SIM to generate 3G traffic with a network, then there would be no security for the telcos.

Because you mention accessing a mobile gateway, it is possible that you only need to simulate an internal interface of the mobile core network.  There is specialist test equipment for doing this, but it costs around 100 000 USD.