# SMS not received...only in certain cases...Carrier/Country?

Tags: android, sms, samsung-mobile, sms-gateway, smsmanager

**I** have a technical issue that I can't resolve because the problem only happens on the **other side of the planet that I'm on**.

So I am hoping someone with a lot more Experience with these technologies can suggest an alternate approach or path to take in order to rectify it, or possibly right out "RECOGNIZE" the source of the problem.

### THE SCENARIO :

I have developed an application for the Samsung Gear2 that sends SMS messages using its host companion android application.

In all tests I perform with the app pair, everything works as expected.

Messages are sent by the android device's SMS manager and received by the recipient no problem, even when adding and removing the leading 1.

*10 and 11 digit numbers to and from the USA, with and without the leading + sign all pass.*

**However**, when sending the apps to Samsung for review and testing, they keep having problems sending certain numbers. As far as I can tell the only thing different between the numbers that send and the numbers that fail is the fact that the first has a leading 0 and the second does not.

This would have to be coupled with the fact that they are testing this functionality
in a different Continent/Country than the 1 where my tests are being done(USA).
As my tests succeed to send and receive the messages regardless of whether 
the number is a 10 digit version or 11 digit version of the same number.

Also discrepancies surfacing from the use of different Carriers (possibly Telecom in Asia) other than the one that I am testing with(Bell - USA)...

To be clear, I am simply composing messages via the Gear2 app and sending it to the android device via Samsung's Accessory Protocol which works flawlessly.

From there I use the basic implementation of the standard

> Android's SMSManager
>
> getDefault()

and

```
sendTextMessage(String destinationAddress, String scAddress, String 

text, PendingIntent sentIntent, PendingIntent deliveryIntent)
```

with all null values exept the "destinationAddress","text",
and the "sentIntent".

---

### THE QUESTION(s) : in order of most to least important

**1. IS THERE a specific "routine" SMS app developers use to maximize the 
success rate**
of sent sms messages no matter what Country or Carrier the user sends the message from or to, and no matter if the entered number contains the leading exit and Country codes?

> (ie: Adding or removing a plus(+) sign,  per-examining the Locale
>   being used and adjusting the number accordingly using some sort of
>   "SMS Numbering Standard",  Altering the Service Center Address / SMSC
>   Address (AT+CSCA),  ect...)?

**2.** IS THERE some sort of information source detailing general "GOTCHAS" to look for
dependent upon the various Cell/SMS service providers/Carriers? (at least 4 that I know of).

**3.** Why would Android's SMSManger report "SMS Sent" if the message wasn't actually delivered.

*NOTE: I realize that one can also listen for the "second" broadcast android sends
confirming that the message was "actually" received by the recipient, but that raises questions concerning how to rectify that situation, if it's at all rectifiable (at least from a programmatic perspective.)*

**4.** Should my app, which is actually a Samsung Gear2 app integrated with an android app,
and merely delegates the responsibility of sending the messages to the android devices SMSManager, be held responsible for the message not being sent?

> NOTE:  I can't help but feel that Samsung is requiring me to handle
>   issues outside the scope and unrelated to the apps intended
>   functionality, Albeit , I do understand that at least part of the
>   issue has to fall back on me by Default, being the nature of the Gear2
>   apps dependance on the android device to complete the intended action
>   started by the Gear2 app, but how far must I go to ensure the standard
>   SMS abilities of a users android device beyond giving helpful feedback
>   as to what the underlying problem may be. I have to assume this
>   problem would exist using the device itself to compose the message
>   instead of the Gear2 app, given the exact same address/number .

**5.** Assuming that the app is being tested in Asia (South Korea, Samsung's Headquarters)... And assuming that the carrier being used to test SMS is SK Telecom

> (Which I think is South Korea's top Carrier)...

Is it Mandatory to start all numbers with a zero in order to successfully send an SMS within the same Country? And if so is that the same in all Countries besides the USA and Canada(Which seem to work either way)?

**6.** Is this a common issue to deal with generally when developing sms applications, or can I single this particular situation out from the rest based on the unique variables introduced by Samsung's over diligent testing practices along with there unfamiliar 
Telephony Service Providers and even more unfamiliar Geo-location/Country-code and numbering schemes.

---

### THE PROBLEM *(only happens during Samsung testing) :

**TEST 1:**

Send SMS from stored contacts with number 010-6627-xxxx (11 digits)

> **Result:**
>
> SMS is reported by android's SMSManager as sent. The recipient
>   immediately receives SMS message.
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> SMS delivery success.

**TEST 2:**

Send SMS from manually entering number 10-6627-xxxx (10 digits) (same number as previous without first 0)

> **Result:**
>
> SMS is reported by android's SMSManager as sent. However, the
>   recipient never receives SMS message.
>
> **Conclusion:**
>
> ?

Unable to duplicate this problem (at least not in the USA) as both :

> 11 digit  numbers (leading 1) **AND** 10 digit numbers
>   (no leading 1)

```
Successfully send the message as expected.
```

The problem only happens during device testing/certification by Samsung's app testing
department, and seemingly only when manually entering the destination address/number.

> Stored Contacts (for some reason) always work.

After being denied certification of an otherwise "GOOD TO GO APPLICATION" ***3 times*** by Samsung for issues UN-recreatable in my own testing environment I find myself turning the good folks at ***SOF*** with this "*HAIL MARY PASS*".

I do not change anything at all about the numbers that are sent to the SMSManager, But I'm wondering if *maybe THAT'S the problem*.

**EXTRA INFO :**
All devices used are using android 4.2 and higher.
My tests were all done using T-Mobile Galaxy phones and sometimes google/Gmail/GoogleVoice
sms/mms service From North Fla. USA.

ON A SIDE NOTE ABOUT SAMSUNG...
Samsung's testers are very sparse with the details of their testing enviroment including what may possibly be the issue from their standpoint which is unfortunate because I'm becoming certain that this issue is Trivial at best and probably easily fixable with a basic understanding of your own Country/Carriers methods for sending successful SMS messages.
 **It seems they are not even making an effort to enlighten me or TO make any neccesary
adjustments to their test numbers as any user would do in order to have a successful result.**

**ANY INSIGHT INTO THIS ISSUE WHATSOEVER WOULD BE IMMENSELY APPRECIATED!!!**

Comment: Can you get hold of a Korean SIM to test in the US?  By the way, I don't think this is a common problem :-)

Comment: Also, maybe the service recommended in the questioner's answer to this question would be helpful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20853026/mimic-3g-network-traffic-of-selected-telco-operator/20972524#20972524

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question. I understand that the Samsung testing process can be quite rigorous.
From reading your info .. have you tried including that leading "0" yourself? E,g when a person manually enters 10 digits without a leading 0, you detect it and add this "0" . Also, how are this digits entered on a gear 2 device ? Do you implement your own keypad and ensure it captures the right digits ?

I guess that would be a starting point ..

V.

Comment: No I haven't tried adding any numbers myself, at least not yet. It would only be in certain areas where a zero is used, for Instance,

Comment: here in the states it would be a one, and I'm pretty sure it's different in each country.So adding a zero myself would only work in cases where the users Country Code was zero (I think). I would need to detect the users location, detect an incomplete number and figure out the appropriate leading digit(s) to add on. It just seems over and beyond the normal procedure used by an app to send a simple text message...But please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: As far as entering the digits on the gear device, Its a simple phone type number pad that also enters alpha characters, similar to the old way phones use to (and still do) use the numbers to double as letters.